# C++ Convert string to float

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to convert a string based number to float. Unfortunately I am getting either the rounded off value or truncated value. How can I fix this.

```
    std::string text = "199102.92";
    float v = std::stof(text);
    std::cout<<v<<std::endl;
```

This results in 199103
Even if I use setprecision and fixed then it only affects the output stream but the value passed into the float variable remains 199103. How can i resort this problem.

I have also used stringstream in c++ but results seem to be the same except it just displays off well.

I need to preserve the decimal upto 2 places.

I have used stof,stod, they all do the same thing.

You may assume that I am working with currencies.

Comment: std::stof() uses the current locale to determine the character used as decimal point. Maybe in your locale it's not the dot but e.g. the comma?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you use `std::setprecision` and `std::fixed` incorrectly.

Following works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


string text = "199102.92";
float v = std::stof(text);
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << v << std::endl;
```

The result is 199102.92

Compiler info: g++ 5.4.0, --std=c++11.

Comment: so the value stored inside v is actually 199102.92 or something else? moreover if I do some math over it say v - 199102.00. , then. set precision and fixed only format the output stream not the stored number.

Comment: It's 199102.921875 but it's due to limitations of floating point representation (IEEE 754 standard). If you need to store the exact value, consider using `long long` to represent floating point values (in this case you need to store mantissa and exponent separately) or use some third-party library.
Also, `double` may have better precision than `float`.